# JDBC Android to Oracle connection

Tags: java, android, oracle, jdbc

I'm writing an app to connect to Android to an Oracle DB. I used ojdbc6 to connect and it only works on emulated devices over android 5. When it fails, it fails for different reasons a) jdbc drivers arent found b) connection immediately fails and is set to null (Network Adapter could not establish connection). Why is this happening? Should I use a different driver?
Thanks.
ps ive seen similar questions on here but dont address the difference in devices that causes some not to work with ojdbc6 additionally, the suggested ojdb14 doesnt for any devices.

Comment: People usually build server side applications talking to Oracle DB exposing REST services that are then consumed by mobile apps.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android

Comment: I'd agree with Boris, for exactly the reasons in the question/answer Morrison linked. If you're interested, the company I work for (CData Software, [www.cdata.com](http://www.cdata.com)) makes a server-side application that proxies live Oracle DB data that may interest you: [http://www.cdata.com/drivers/oracle/cloud/](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/oracle/cloud/).

Comment: Thanks but that's a little pricey for my purposes; which is to connect to DB with one personal device for quick customer lookups